# Crashes on Xcode 7.1 while using Xibs

Tags: xcode, crash

I recently started using Xibs and have been experiencing many crashes.  I am not sure if it is due to the Xibs or something else but i thought i'd mention that.  I see the error report and then i click re-open and the project opens but the project folder is red indicating it is missing.  If I re-open the project using file-open the project folder is no-longer red nor missing.  Has anyone experienced this crash?

[image: the crash log]